# Тормозит google chrome при переключении сети

Tags: google-chrome, wifi, lan

При подключении к разным сетям wifi или переключении lan/wifi или еще какие-нибудь манипуляции с сетью Google Chrome начинает безбожно тупит несколько минут. Потом отходит и начинает нормально работать. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос не относится к программированию или системному администрированию.

Answer (score 1):

В общем решение проблемы оказалось простым до безобразия - нужно в настройках самого хрома (Настройки / Показать дополнительные настройки / Изменить настройки проски-сервера / вкладка "соединения" / настройка сети) убрать галочку "автоматическое определение параметров"...

[image: форма на которой нужно убрать галочку]

Почему она тут стоит по умолчанию - не понятно, но без нее гораздо лучше